# WordPress Development / insert $post obj into an array

Tags: wordpress

After the loop is ended, in my array `$arr` every property `$post->prio_title` has the same value (the last of the cycle), even if I check it just before insert it into the array. How is this possible?

```
foreach ($ser as $v) {
  $post->prio_title = $v->name;
  print_r($post);
  $arr[] = $post;
}

print_r($arr);
```

The first print returns: (I don't post everything but only the interested lines)

```
[prio_title] => Serie 3000
[prio_title] => Serie 4000
[prio_title] => Serie 8
```

The second:

```
[prio_title] => Serie 8
[prio_title] => Serie 8
[prio_title] => Serie 8
```

Comment: Would be handy if you post more code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$post is a reference. This is why all the elements get the value of the last cycle.

Problem fixed with

```
$arr[] = clone $post;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$arr = array();
```

when you need to define a new array. for example.

```
$arr = array();

foreach ($ser as $v) {

  $post->prio_title = $v->name;

  print_r($post);

  $arr[] = $post;

}

print_r($arr);
```

Comment: Hello Jayr, thanks for the suggestion, but I have already declared the array outside the foreach as you shown me. It is not this the problem.